# backbone.js scroll event with handler is not unbinding

Tags: backbone.js, jquery

I've binded window's scroll event to a view's method like:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, 'handleScrolling');
    $(window).off('scroll', this.handleScrolling).on('scroll', this.handleScrolling);
  }
})
```

I see this is not working. If this callback is triggered as many times as this view is instantiated. However, if I remove handler from `off`, then it is correctly unbinding and triggers only once per scrolling. Like:

```
$(window).off('scroll').on('scroll', this.handleScrolling);
```

Any idea why this is happening? I dont want to remove all callbacks from this event as other views/codes may bind event to it which will make app behaving unexpected.

Is there any better way of binding events to window/document or other element outside the scope of current view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
_.bindAll(this, 'handleScrolling');
```

That's equivalent to:

```
this.handleScrolling = _.bind(this.handleScrolling, this);
```

so each time you instantiate your view, you're working with a brand new function in `this.handleScrolling`. Then you do this:

```
$(window).off('scroll', this.handleScrolling)
```

But that won't do anything since the `this.handleScrolling` function that you attached with `on`:

```
.on('scroll', this.handleScrolling);
```

isn't the same function as the `this.handleScrolling` function that you're trying to `.off`. The result is that each time you create a new instance of your view, you're leaving the old scroll handler in place and adding a new one.

The proper solution (IMO) is to add a [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) method to properly clean things up:

```
remove: function() {
    $(window).off('scroll', this.handleScrolling);
    return Backbone.View.prototype.remove.apply(this);
}
```

and then call `view.remove()` before creating the new view.

Comment: Now i'm stuck with this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241694/backbone-js-requestpager-conditionally-exclude-paramater-from-url. Any help please?

Comment: Great post. I like namespacing using `app:context`. For example, `$(window).on("scroll.app:productsView")`. Helps keeps things organized. Thanks for the post!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a new instance of the handler `this.handleScrolling` in each call.

so when jQuery tries to remove the specific handler it will not find the handler in the event registry, so it will not be able to remove it.

Problem: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EuzGG/1/)

I would suggest using event namespaces here

```
$(window).off('scroll.myview').on('scroll.myview', this.handleScrolling);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EuzGG/2/)

Another solution is to use a shared handler like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EuzGG/3/)

Comment: The underlying problem is that `_.bindAll(this, 'handleScrolling')` replaces `this.handleScrolling` with a wrapper function each time it is called.

Comment: @muistooshort in that case wouldn't be namespace be a better idea

Comment: @muistooshort Also what I don't understand is if the OP is not interested in the underlying instance why is the context binding done at all because from what I can see only the last instance event is retained all all others are removed

Comment: There's nothing wrong with namespacing, that's just as valid as anything else but maybe more jQuery-ish than Backbone-ish; you really should be calling `remove` on your Backbone views though, not doing so can leave zombies. The binding could be cargo-cult programming or `handleScrolling` could care about what its `this` is, can't say without knowing what `handleScrolling` is doing.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Your solution is really simple and thanks for that. However, I'm preferring the backbone-ish one as I eventually need to tear down my views.