# Backbone.js requestPager conditionally exclude paramater from URL

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

RequestPager sends all the attributes in server_api to the request as query string. However, sometime I want to exclude a parameter on some condition. This is how, i'm setting the param:

```
server_api: {
        query: function () {
            return this.searchQuery
        },
        type: function(){ return this.searchType }
}
```

If `this.searchQuery` is empty, it makes the URL like `?query=&type=1`. But I don't want to send `query` or `type` when it's empty or when my some other condition fails.

I know the dirty way like:

```
if(!myCollection.searchQuery){
    delete(myCollection.server_api.licensed);
}
```

But this is not maintainable. Because text time I've to create this function. So, I'm looking for a better way of doing this. Any Help?

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone.paginator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [how `server_api` is used](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone.paginator/blob/master/lib/backbone.paginator.js#L792):

```
_.each(_.result(self, "server_api"), function(value, key){
  if( _.isFunction(value) ) {
    value = _.bind(value, self);
    value = value();
  }
  queryAttributes[key] = value;
});
```

you'll see that it uses [`_.result`](http://underscorejs.org/#result):

> **result** `_.result(object, property)`
>
> If the value of the named property is a function then invoke it;
>   otherwise, return it.
>
> ```
> var object = {cheese: 'crumpets', stuff: function(){ return 'nonsense'; }};
> _.result(object, 'cheese');
> => "crumpets"
> _.result(object, 'stuff');
> => "nonsense"
> ```

That means that you can make `server_api` a function which returns the appropriate object.

Comment: Before I read your answer, I've already looked in this piece of code. but I mis-interpreted the purpose of `_.result` here. I was thinking it does this for it's (`server_api`) attributes. thanks a lot